# Cómo desplazarse a la izquierda los elementos de un Array en Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

estoy intentando desplazar a la izquierda los elementos de un array, que el que quede a fuera se pierde, para así poder añadir un nuevo valor al final.
Vaya como un sistema de log con capacidad limitada a 10 elementos

```kotlin
var arr = IntArray(10){0}

//@todo rotar elementos array izquierda

arr[9] = 300 //añadir nuevo valor
```

Antes de añadir el valor, como se rotar el array hacia la izquierda?

Comment: Hola!Es posible utilizar otra estructura de datos, o necesariamente tiene que ser una arreglo?

Comment: En principio habia pensado en usar un array de enteros por la simplicidad de estructura

Comment: Se puede utilizar un array también. en el ejemplo que pusiste, arr[9] = 300, entiendo que este elemento se debería insertar en la posición '0'. Tu quieres tener el comportamiento de una cola pero con una cantidad de elementos determinada cierto?

Comment: Si eso mismo, si se tiene 1,2,3,4,5..9, al añadir 10 a la última posición, quede 2,3,4...9,10, el 1 como ya es viejo se pierda, más o menos como un stack de log de 10 entradas, que las viejas dejen paso para las nuevas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podrías intentar es lo siguiente:

- Crear una extension con el comportamiento de size:

luego de eso crearías tu estructura de la siguiente manera:

```
//extension function
fun Queue<Int>.pushElement(element: Int){
    if(this.size >= 5){ // En este caso le he puesto 5, para tu caso es 10
        this.remove()
    }
this.add(element)}
//.........
val nums: Queue<Int> = LinkedList<Int>()
    nums.pushElement(1)
    nums.pushElement(2)
    nums.pushElement(3)
    nums.pushElement(4)
    nums.pushElement(5)
    nums.pushElement(6)

    nums.forEach {
        it.log() // 2 3 4 5 6 [ El uno se eliminó]
    }
```

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Me sirve, ya que ahora tenia que cambiar el array por una lista, por tener que calcular si habian suficientes muestras y con size en mi caso me devolvia siempre el total por ser fijo, con tu solución me devuelve exactamente las entradas que hay +1

Answer (score 0):

Buscando a ver si existia alguna función estilo `array_shift` como en php, he creado lo siguiente para kotlin

**Función arrayShift()**

```kotlin
fun arrayShift(arr: IntArray): IntArray {
    val x = arr.size - 1
    arr.forEachIndexed { i, _ ->
        if (i < x) arr[i] = arr[i+ 1]
    }
    return arr
}
```

su uso `arr = arrayShift(arr)`

**Extención Kotlin IntArray.shl()**

O bien si se quiere añadir una exteción

```kotlin
fun IntArray.shl() {
    val maxIndex = this.size - 1
    this.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
        if (index < maxIndex) this[index] = this[index + 1]
    }
}
```

su uso `arr.shl()`